# parsing serial numbers tags from xml python

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file a shorter version is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
<_1>
<member_id>AFCE6DB97D4CD67D</member_id>
</_1>
<_2>
<member_id>AFCE6DB97D4CD67D</member_id>
</_2>
</DATA>
```

I am using the following code to parse

```
tree = ElementTree.parse(args['inputxml'])
root = tree.getroot()
for dat in root:
    memberID = dat.find('member_id').text
```

I am able to parse the member id but not sure how to parse the serial number ``` <_1>``<_2> ```etc.  This number keeps extending with every new record in xml.

Comment: and what's the issue?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I don't know how to parse this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [xpath()](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html):

```
xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA>
<_1>
<member_id>AFCE6DB97D4CD67D</member_id>
</_1>
<_2>
<member_id>AFCE6DB97D4CD67D</member_id>
</_2>
</DATA>"""


root = etree.fromstring(xml)
members = root.xpath("//member_id")

for m in members:
    print m.text, m.getparent().tag
```

This prints:

```
AFCE6DB97D4CD67D _1
AFCE6DB97D4CD67E _2
```

Comment: This i am able to parse with the code that I have given.  Would it be possible to parse the serial numbers?

Comment: Edited answer to print 'serial numbers'